# Adjacency Lists, Store edges as Linked Lists or Sets?

Tags: python, graph, graph-theory

I've been learning a lot about graph theory and graphs in general. I have been looking for my first job as an engineer and the technical interviews have definitely pushed my scope of knowledge.

When I read about Adjacency lists, the literature always references a list, with indexes representing a vertex and linked lists stored under each index representing edges connected to that vertex.

Before reading this material I was making my graphs as hash tables, with each key being a vertex and each value being a set of edges.

My idea was fast lookup and deletion time. I was solving basic problems involving DFS with this setup and it worked fine.

**My question**: is there any downside representing a graph as a hash table, `k=vertex`, `v=set{edges}`, or any real benefit of using arrays/linked list to store edges, switching my approach?

Thanks in advance for helping me grasp the basics!

Comment: Hash tables are quite efficient for smaller datasets; however, very inefficient for larger data. In that case, a linked list would be best.

Comment: "for sufficiently large data <bar> is more efficient than <foo>" it is kind of a blank statement that can be applied to any algorithm comparison. It would be a lot more useful accompanied by some ballpark for what is "larger data" (where the trade-offs stop to pay) in this context for Python running in a modern computer. In fact the OP should be profiling it - Python is surprisingly counter-intuitive regarding performance.

Comment: I've been using that approach for hobby competitive programming, where nodes are in millions and time limit is 2 seconds, it worked fine.